# "often" vs. "oftentimes"

Tags: pleonasms

“often” vs. “oftentimes”

Is “oftentimes” a pleonasm? My current understanding is that “often” denotes frequent occurrence. If “often” communicates frequent occurrence, then what need is there to append “times,” a temporal aspect already communicated by the word “often?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not really a pleonasm.  It’s more of a throwback to times gone by. Both *oftentime* and *oftentimes* are nothing but extended forms of the shorter *oft-time* or *oft-times*, but which are still pretty old-timey in feel. The OED says that all four of these are now variously considered *obsolete*, *rare*, *archaic*, *literary*, or *poetic*. You are more apt to find them in literature than in pedestrian banter.

- **oftentime**: *rare*
- **oftentimes**: *archaic* or *literary*
- **oft-time**: *obsolete* or *archaic*
- **oft-times**: *archaic* or *poetic*

Take your pick. No matter which you choose, they all boil down to the same shared meaning:

> Many times; on many occasions, or in many cases; frequently, often.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it includes the OED designation for **oftentimes**. However, the OED's designation as _archaic_ or _literary_ seems more prescriptive than descriptive, and as such, it does not explain why esteemed public figures--such as famous professors and news anchors on nationally syndicated television programs--use the word **oftentimes** in non-literary contexts. One might make the point that some of those esteemed public figures are borderline-archaic themselves, but such a characterization would fail to explain their use of redundant lexemes.

Answer (score 1):

"oftentimes" is a synonym for "often", but also carries a connotation of separate *occasions* that "often" does not. For example,

> I oftentimes check my watch often while waiting at the doctors office.

works better than

> I often check my watch often while waiting at the doctors office.

Comment: I don't think either of those works very well with "often" repeated like that, but I find "I often check my watch" more normal than "I oftentimes check my watch".

Comment: @Hellion I agree, and was just trying to think of an example of how *oftentimes* refers to occasions rather than instances...it's forced of course.